# AWS - check console access with python requests

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-requests

I'd like to check AWS console access having account, username and password. I'm using python requests library. I tried to send "raw" request containing all the data I have: (`{'username': username, 'password': password, 'account': account}`) to `https://us-east-1.signin.aws.amazon.com/authenticate` but got 403 all the time. I saw there are other data in browser request, for example `code_challenge` but I have no idea how to generate it.

Is this even possible (even in different way, using some API for example)? If so I also wondering how to handle MFA, if it's set.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? That is, _why_ are you wanting to do this, rather than _how_ to do it? Are you wanting to achieve some form of automatic sign-in, or federated login? Please tell us more!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hi, I'm working on automation which checks console access for a number of accounts. All I need is to be sure that username/password are valid (I get credentials from password manager and check if login is possible). No other actions (at this moment) in the console are needed.